# Apache ReWrite rule for &amp; to &

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Already doing this rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now the requested url is

```
https://www.example.com/abc.php?a=&amp;b=abc&amp;c=def&amp;d=0&amp;e=1
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/abc.php?a=&b=abc&c=def&d=0&e=1
```

Comment: It may be relevant to know how you get an invalid URL in the first place. Perhaps it can be fixed from source.

Answer (score 0):

add the NE tag at the end of the rule (No Escape):

```
RewriteRule (...) [NE]
```

Comment: don't understand kindly explain

Comment: If I recall correctly, the `NE` tag applies to URL-encoded hexadecimal sequences (`%3D`), not HTML entities.